# SqLite error near OUTPUT

Tags: sqlite, output

I try to Update my table and return IDs of updated rows. here is the command:

```
UPDATE messages SET status = 2 OUTPUT inserted.ID WHERE status=1 and sender!=@person
```

But I get sqlite error for my OUTPUT clause.
I use version 3 (the mono version for mobile)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SQLite, the [UPDATE statement](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_update.html) has no OUTPUT clause.

In an embedded database, there is no client/server communication overhead.
Just get the IDs with a SELECT.